# int to NSString issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I use the following statement for into to NSString conversion (with a find/replace)

```
curr_rep_date = [tmpRptDt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:tmpYrVal withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:(tmpCurrYearInt-1)]];
```

I have declared

```
int tmpYrVal;
NSMutableString *tmp_dt,*curr_rep_date;
```

But the program seems to be crashing and the debugger is not giving any hint.

Could someone help me with the issue and what would be the correct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of problems here.

Firstly, `sringByReplacingOcurrancesOfString:withString:` is expecting `NSString`s as parameters, not `int`s. That's the reason why it crashes. The method Is attempting to send a message to a primitive type, not an object.

Secondly, you need to use a proper format string for the `stringWithFormat:` method. This is the same as how `NSLog` works.

A format string can look like `@"some text %d"`. It would then be followed by a comma separated list of values to be used in place of the % placeholders.

Example:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIntValue];
```

Will effectively turn your int into a string, as it creates a new string with a format using your int.

Answer (score 1):

You invoked the stringWithFormat - Method without a format string. [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", (tmpCurrYearInt-1)] should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the format

```
curr_rep_date = [tmpRptDt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:tmpYrVal withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (tmpCurrYearInt-1)]];
```

Comment: I replaced with the above line. Still the program is crashing.

Comment: Look at my answer. You can't pass an int as the first argument to sringByReplacingOcurrancesOfString:withString: it takes a string not an int.

Comment: Hi Jasarien..So could you please provide me the complete correct statement usage.

Comment: I think I got the correct usage now. It should be;
curr_rep_date = [tmpRptDt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tmpYrVal] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(tmpCurrYearInt-1)]];
   
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Basic int to NSString conversion works like this:

```
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intNumber];
```